# Context menu got empty separator

Tags: finder, shortcut-menu

I’ve got empty lines in context menus, what is it and how could I get rid of it?

[image: Context menu]

Answer (score 1):

Got it, it was an outdated TotalFinder plugin. Installed the newest and context menu is OK now.